# Custom CursorAdapter won't display data

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I've implemented a custom `CursorAdapter`. This adapter takes data from a `Cursor` and deposits most of it into a `ListView`. One of the fields in the `ListView` needs data from a different table, so I need to query the database again to set that piece in the view.  My `ListView` seems to be working, as before I had no data in the db it was properly displaying my empty tag, `"no data in the db"`. Now that there is data in the db, the `ListView` shows nothing! Here is my custom adapter:

```
    public class ScheduleAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mHomeAway, mOppFK, mLocation, mWhen, mOutcome, mType, mPlayed;
    private String teamName;

    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mHomeAway = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHHOMEAWAY);
        mOppFK = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHOPPFK);
        mLocation = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHLOCATION);
        mWhen = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHWHEN);
        mOutcome = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHOUTCOME);
        mType = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHTYPE);
        mPlayed = c.getColumnIndex(ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SCHPLAYED);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_main_list, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView homeAway = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvVsAt);
        TextView oppName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleListOpponent);
        TextView location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleListLocation);
        TextView outcomeWhen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleDateTimeResult);
        TextView gameType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleType);

        ScoreMasterDB dbInfo = new ScoreMasterDB(context);
        try {
            dbInfo.open();
            teamName = dbInfo.getTeamName(cursor.getInt(mOppFK));
            dbInfo.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        homeAway.setText(cursor.getString(mHomeAway));
        oppName.setText(teamName);
        location.setText(cursor.getString(mLocation));

        //set game time or outcome
        if(cursor.getInt(mPlayed) == 0){
            outcomeWhen.setText(cursor.getString(mWhen));

            //set text style for outcome
            if(cursor.getInt(mOutcome) == 1){
                outcomeWhen.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.greenWinText);
            }
        }

        gameType.setText(cursor.getString(mType));

    }
}
```

Here is my call to this adapter:

```
// get schedule cursor
            scheduleInfo = dbInfo.getScheduleCursor(teamID, seasonID);
            startManagingCursor(scheduleInfo);

            ScheduleAdapter scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleMain.this, scheduleInfo);
            setListAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
```

EDIT:
The activity that is calling the custom adapter is supposed to display the team's schedule.  It does so by first showing a dialog to select the team, then showing another dialog to choose the appropriate season.  It then queries the db for the schedule with the matching teamID and seasonID.  The reason for the custom adapter is that the schedule will list the opponent as an integer foreign key, so I need to query the db in the adapter to grab the appropriate team name for the opponent.

Here is the activity (its quite a lot of code)

```
    package com.scoremaster.pro;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScheduleMain extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener,
        OnClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {

    Dialog selectTeam, selectSeason, newSeason;
    Cursor teamInfo, seasons, scheduleInfo;
    ScoreMasterDB dbInfo;
    ListView diaList, diaSeason;
    int teamID, seasonID;
    String teamNameG;
    Button addNewSeason;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_main);

        selectTeam = new Dialog(ScheduleMain.this);
        selectTeam.setContentView(R.layout.schedule_main_dialog);
        selectTeam.setTitle("Select Team");

        dbInfo = new ScoreMasterDB(this);
        try {
            dbInfo.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        teamInfo = dbInfo.getTeamsCursor();
        startManagingCursor(teamInfo);

        if (teamInfo.getCount() == 0) {
            Intent createTeamIntent = new Intent(
                    "com.scoremaster.pro.CREATETEAM");
            createTeamIntent.putExtra("fromSchedule", true);
            startActivity(createTeamIntent);
        }

        String[] columns = { ScoreMasterDB.KEY_TEAMNAME };
        int[] to = { R.id.tvTeamSelectList };

        //Bundle scheduleBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        //int whatToDo = scheduleBundle.getInt(")

        diaList = (ListView) selectTeam.findViewById(R.id.lvScheduleDialog);
        SimpleCursorAdapter teamListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                ScheduleMain.this, R.layout.team_select_list, teamInfo,
                columns, to);
        diaList.setAdapter(teamListAdapter);
        diaList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        selectTeam.show();

    }

    // listview onClick events
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.lvScheduleDialog:
            selectTeam.dismiss();
            teamInfo.moveToPosition(position);

            // set data on ScheduleMain
            TextView teamName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleTeam);
            TextView teamAbbrev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleAbbrev);
            TextView teamLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleLevel);
            LinearLayout layTeam = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layScheduleTeam);
            Button bAddSchedule = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddGame);

            teamNameG = teamInfo.getString(1);

            teamName.setText(teamInfo.getString(1));
            teamAbbrev.setText(teamInfo.getString(2));
            teamLevel.setText(teamInfo.getString(3));
            bAddSchedule.setText("Add Game to Schedule");
            bAddSchedule.setClickable(true);

            teamID = teamInfo.getInt(0);

            // set button if no team
            if (teamInfo.getCount() == 0) {

            }

            // set listeners for bAddGame and laySheduleTeam
            bAddSchedule.setOnClickListener(this);
            layTeam.setOnClickListener(this);

            // get season information
            selectSeason = new Dialog(ScheduleMain.this);
            selectSeason.setContentView(R.layout.schedule_season_dialog);
            selectSeason.setTitle("Select Season");
            seasons = dbInfo.getSeasonsCursor(teamID);
            startManagingCursor(seasons);

            String[] columns = { ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SEANAME };
            int[] to = { R.id.tvTeamSelectList };

            // set select season dialog listview elements
            diaSeason = (ListView) selectSeason
                    .findViewById(R.id.lvSeasonDialog);
            SimpleCursorAdapter seasonListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    ScheduleMain.this, R.layout.team_select_list, seasons,
                    columns, to);
            diaSeason.setAdapter(seasonListAdapter);
            diaSeason.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            diaSeason.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

            // set add button listenter
            Button addSeason = (Button) selectSeason
                    .findViewById(R.id.bAddSeason);
            addSeason.setOnClickListener(this);

            // show dialog
            selectSeason.show();
            break;
        case R.id.lvSeasonDialog:
            // get seasonID
            selectSeason.dismiss();
            seasons.moveToPosition(position);
            seasonID = seasons.getInt(0);

            // get schedule cursor
            scheduleInfo = dbInfo.getScheduleCursor(teamID, seasonID);
            startManagingCursor(scheduleInfo);
            //scheduleInfo.moveToFirst();

            //String[] columns1 = {ScoreMasterDB.KEY_SEANAME};
            //int[] to1 = {R.id.tvScheduleAddVsAt};
            //SimpleCursorAdapter scheduleAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ScheduleMain.this, R.layout.schedule_main_list, seasons, columns1, to1);
            ScheduleAdapter scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleMain.this, scheduleInfo);
            setListAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
            break;

        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAddSeason:
            selectSeason.dismiss();
            newSeason = new Dialog(ScheduleMain.this);
            newSeason.setContentView(R.layout.schedule_new_season);
            newSeason.setTitle("New Season");

            TextView teamName = (TextView) newSeason
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvNewSeasonTeamName);
            teamName.setText("Create new season for the " + teamNameG);

            addNewSeason = (Button) newSeason
                    .findViewById(R.id.bSubmitNewSeason);
            addNewSeason.setOnClickListener(this);
            newSeason.show();
            break;
        case R.id.bSubmitNewSeason:
            TextView seasonName = (TextView) newSeason
                    .findViewById(R.id.etNewSeasonName);
            String submitSeason = seasonName.getText().toString();
            if (submitSeason.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ScheduleMain.this, "Please enter a season name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    dbInfo.insertSeason(teamID, submitSeason);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }

            break;
        case R.id.bAddGame:
            Intent addGame = new Intent("com.scoremaster.pro.ADDGAME");
            addGame.putExtra("teamID", teamID);
            addGame.putExtra("seasonID", seasonID);
            startActivity(addGame);

            break;
        case R.id.layScheduleTeam:
            selectTeam.show();
            break;
        }

    }

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.lvSeasonDialog) {
            seasons.moveToPosition(position);
            int rowID = seasons.getInt(0);
            dbInfo.removeSeason(rowID);
            selectSeason.dismiss();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Here is the getScheduleCursor() method in the DB class

```
    public Cursor getScheduleCursor(int teamID, int seasonID){
    String[] columnsSch = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_SCHHOMEAWAY, KEY_SCHOPPFK, KEY_SCHLOCATION,  KEY_SCHWHEN, KEY_SCHOUTCOME, KEY_SCHTYPE, KEY_SCHPLAYED}; 
    Cursor c = scoreMasterDB.query(DB_SCHEDULE_TABLE, columnsSch, KEY_SCHTEAMFK + "=" + teamID + " AND " + KEY_SCHSEASON + "=" + seasonID, null, null, null, null); 

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, the query in `getScheduleCursor` returns any row?

Comment: You should use startManagingCursor() it's deprecated, instead use LoaderManager.

Comment: @Chopin, it is returning rows.

Comment: @Se_bastiaan , I will research the LoaderManager and work it in, thanks.  Do you think that that could be the problem?  The other piece of the puzzle is that information used in the cursor is coming from an alertdialog listview.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, you still have to use the CursorAdapter when using LoaderManager..

Comment: Have you tried just using a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: Well, I need to get the teamName from a different table, so I needed to perform a different query.  Basically, my first query returns the team's data as a foreign key, so I need to query the tblTeams to get the team name.  I was trying to make it happen in the list adapter, but I suppose I should figure how to do a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ScheduleAdapter`, when inflating the view, use the version of `inflate()` that does not attach to the root view:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_main_list, parent, false);
}
```

Also note, it would be better if you include the `teamName` in the original cursor (along with or replacing `mOppFK`) rather than creating a new connection to the database to get it when binding the view, cause you're making a new connection and query the DB for every item added to the `ListView`.

**EDIT:** things you can improve:

**A)** Instead of made your activity to implement `OnItemClickListener` (and the other interfaces), use an anonymous type when you need to pass it to `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
diaList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

**B)** To perform a `JOIN` (and avoid open a new connection inside the adapter), use a `SQLiteQueryBuilder` to build your query expression:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
qb.setTables("foo LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON (foo.id = bar.foo_id)")

Cursor cursor = qb.query(...);
```

**C)** Not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

You want to restart your activity? Why not just open the first dialog again?

**D)** I feel more comfortable creating a new `Intent` in this way:

```
Intent createTeamIntent = new Intent(this, CREATETEAM.class));
```

If you're inside a listener, you can't use `this` to pass as context (as it doesn't refer to the activity). In such cases, you can declare an atributte in the activity:

```
Context context;
```

Initialize it in `OnCreate`:

```
this.context = this;
```

And then use it whenever you need it, by simply calling `context`.

Comment: Well, I tried that and it didn't work. Then I tried wiping the data on the emulator.  Ran the app again and now there is a nullPointExcep happening earlier in the DB class that hasn't been touched in days.  So frustrating!!!  I'm going to rearrange some code and see if the DB class has any hidden problems that could be related to my original problem.

Comment: Oh, that's bad :( You can make use of a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) to mock your real cursor and abstract you from the DB, and then determine whether the problem is in the DB class or in the adapter (or somewhere else).

Comment: Well, I just tried what I said in my previous comment, and your adapter works fine (but commented the `try .. catch ..` block inside `bindView` and got the team name directly from my `MatrixCursor`). Also, what I posted in my answer was neccesary for the adapter to work, so I guess the `newView` method has never been called in your tests, pointing the problem it's outside the adapter.

Comment: Well, I've fixed the DB class, and tested various things.  There is data in tblSchedules and getSchedulesCursor is still properly retrieving data.  I set a breakpoint in the bindView and it is never breaking there which makes me think somehow bind view is never being called.  I have my db open() set to throw so I have to have the try/catch in there.  I'll do a bit of research and try to see what MatrixCursor is and see if that helps.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion of using `MatrixCursor` was for testing purposes only, to isolate the DB access layer and only test the adapter. It's not a replacement of a SQLite Cursor. What it lets to do, is manually define the columns of a cursor and populate it with an `addRow` method (will paste the code I've used if you want to see it in detail). Can you post the code of your activity and the DB class?

Comment: I've added code to the OP for you.  Let me know if you need any other pieces.  Thanks for all your time so far!

Comment: Figured it out.  Turns out, it was a problem in the layout! I've used the same layout with a simple cursor adapter in the past and it  was doing silly things to the listview.  That being said, your fix with the inflater did the trick.  Thanks again so much for all of your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Sorry I couldn't reply earlier, I've been quite busy. I did see your activity's code when you added it, but can't find anything suspicious. Anyway, I saw various things you can do to improve your code, I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: Thanks you for your advise.  I'm just getting started learning how to program to begin a quest for a career change.  If you don't mind can I pick your brain about the suggestions you made and why?  I just want to learn how to do things the "right" way. A)Why use anonymous listenter callbacks?  Better performance or tidier code?  D)Why create the attribute `context` instead of just using `ScheduleMain.this`?  Thanks again, I've already begun adjusting my code per your suggestions, just wanted to clarify why :)

Comment: No problem! A) I'm not sure about performance, but I think the code it's clearer in that way. D) I missed that, you are right about using `ScheduleMain.this`. I'm pretty new to Android too, but feel free to ask. And good luck in your career!